# Pandas DataFrame Pivot removes column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am Working on a Dataframe and try to use the Pivot function but it doesnt really work the way i hope.

This is my DataFrame

```
data = {
    'shop': ['Berlin', 'Berlin', 'Los Angeles', 'Los Angeles', 'Paris', 'Paris'],
    'month': ['202209', '202209', '202209', '202208', '202208', '202208'],
    'revenue': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
}

    shop            month   revenue
0   Berlin          202209  10
1   Berlin          202209  20
2   Los Angeles     202209  30
3   Los Angeles     202208  40
4   Paris           202208  50
5   Paris           202208  60
```

What i want it to look like:

```
  shop          202208  202209
0 Berlin        0       10
1 Berlin        0       20
2 Los Angeles   0       30
3 Los Angeles   40      0
4 Paris         50      60
5 Paris         60      0
```

My Code (One of many things i tried)

```
result_df = data_df.pivot(columns='month', values='revenue')
```

What i get:

```
    202208  202209
0   NaN     10
1   NaN     20
2   NaN     30
3   40      NaN
4   50      NaN
5   60      NaN
```

I can handle the NaN values, but i dont understand why i loose the shop information

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You don't have revenue in `202209` month for `Paris` shop, so it shows Nan correctly

Comment: Also, you need to add `.fillna(0)` to replace the NaNs by zeros

Comment: try this one `result_df = data_df.pivot(columns=['month', 'shop'], values='revenue').fillna(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you didnt get shop information . Its not used in PIVOT layer. Here is my view on this,

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'shop': ['Berlin', 'Berlin', 'Los Angeles', 'Los Angeles', 'Paris', 'Paris'],
    'month': ['202209', '202209', '202209', '202208', '202208', '202208'],
    'revenue': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
}

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
result_df = data_df.groupby(['shop', 'month'])['revenue'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
print(result_df)
```

Here is the output,

[Display output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXzQo.png)

Comment: This code aggregates `revenue` which seems sensible although it is not what the OP was expecting.

Comment: If you see the check the display output. isnt matching?. I just removed the duplicates

Answer (score 1):

I think this works:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'shop': ['Berlin', 'Berlin', 'Los Angeles', 'Los Angeles', 'Paris', 'Paris'],
    'month': ['202209', '202209', '202209', '202208', '202208', '202208'],
    'revenue': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
}

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

result_df = data_df.pivot_table(index=['shop', data_df.groupby('shop').cumcount()], columns='month', values='revenue', fill_value=0)
result_df = result_df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
result_df.columns.name = None

print(result_df)
```

`index=['shop', data_df.groupby('shop').cumcount()]` specifies the columns that will be used as the index: The 'shop' column is used as the first level of the index, and the result of `data_df.groupby('shop').cumcount()` is used as the second level. The `cumcount` function is used to generate sequential counts for each group of the 'shop' column.

`columns='month'` specifies that the 'month' column will be used as the columns of the new data frame.

`values='revenue'` says that the 'revenue' column will be used as the values for the cells

`fill_value=0` sets the value for cells where there is no data to 0.

Answer (score 1):

When you pivot, the original index of your DataFrame becomes the new index in the pivoted DataFrame. In your case, you're pivoting on the 'month' column, which turns it into the columns of the new DataFrame. However, since 'shop' is not set as an index or a column to pivot around, it's not included in the final result.

To get the desired result, you might want to use the `pivot_table` method instead, which allows more flexibility. Also, the expected output you've provided seems a bit unusual for a pivot operation because each shop appears twice for the same month with different revenue values. Usually, a pivot operation aggregates these values.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'shop': ['Berlin', 'Berlin', 'Los Angeles', 'Los Angeles', 'Paris', 'Paris'],
    'month': ['202209', '202209', '202209', '202208', '202208', '202208'],
    'revenue': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
}

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

result_df = data_df.pivot_table(index='shop', columns='month', values='revenue', fill_value=0, aggfunc='sum').reset_index()

print(result_df)
```